# How to add Navmesh to existing Aframe (v1.3.0)?

Tags: aframe, navmesh

I don't want the player to go through walls. I tried aframe extras but it doesn't work in current aframe version. Is there any other way or solution that works in Aframe 1.3.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the simple-navmesh-constraint components from AdaRoseCanon ( it's working fine with a-frame 1.3.0):

Source code here:  https://github.com/AdaRoseCannon/aframe-xr-boilerplate

Demo here: https://aframe-xr-starterkit.glitch.me/